# Angular.JS - Error on adding Controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new in [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs). What I am trying to do is adding a simple controller in an angular app. So, my code is like this-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="">
            <div ng-init="mySwitch=true">
                <p>
                <button ng-disabled="mySwitch">Click Me!</button>
                </p>
                <p>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mySwitch"/>Button Disable
                </p>
                <p>
                {{ mySwitch }}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

So, it is working perfectly-

[image]

When I addd `ng-controller="anything"` as such...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="">
            <div ng-controller="anything" ng-init="mySwitch=true">
                <p>
                <button ng-disabled="mySwitch">Click Me!</button>
                </p>
                <p>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mySwitch"/>Button Disable
                </p>
                <p>
                {{ mySwitch }}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Nothing seems to work.

[image]

Can anyone please help, what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: looks like you need to define a controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have not defined a controller. Observe the following...

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
[...]
```

---

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.mySwitch = true;
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/pyd0h3x1/) - working demo

And as always, refer to the [Understanding Controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) docs for more information.

Answer (score 1):

in the first step you need to declare a name for your app

for exemple

Module.js

```
var home = angular.module("home",['ngRoute']);
```

after that call this var in your controller

Controller.js

```
home.controller('homeController',function($scope){
  $scope.switch = value;
});
```

in your code html

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="home">

<div ng-controller="homeController" >
 {{switch}}
</div>
```

Comment: why do you have a dependency of `ngRoute` in this? Also, what is tangibly different in your answer than the one I posted earlier?

Comment: only new information my friend cause if you separate the code in folder it make that easy to manage